# Elastic Search NEST - Search returns no records when we mention Type name

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Tried Code:-

```
public class Company
{
    public long Number { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

My problem is : If I mention Type name within Search Tag I couldn't get any result.

1) Shows Result

```
var rowsList= client.Search(s => s.MatchAll()).Documents.ToList();
```

2) Returns 0 rows

```
var newr = client.Search<Company>(s => s.MatchAll()).Documents.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The typed search defaults to

`/[inferred_index]/[inferred_typename]/_search`

If you want to search through all indices and types you will have to explicit about it

```cs
client.Search<Company>(s=>s
    .AllIndices()
    .AllTypes()
    .MatchAll()
)
```

this will do the search on `/_search`

You can control how nest infers indices and type names like so:

```cs
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri)
    .SetDefaultIndex("my-default-index")
    .MapDefaultTypeNames(d=>d
       .Add(typeof(Company), "company-type")
    )
    MapDefaultTypeIndices(d=>d
        .Add(typeof(Company), "company-index")
    )
    SetDefaultTypeNameInferrer(s=>s.ToLowerInvariant())
```

Now if you search for `<Company>` it will default to `/company-index/company-type/_search`

if you do a search for `<Person>` it will query on `/my-default-index/person/_search`.